# Intersection of rectangular and polar equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles, polar-coordinates

Find the points of intersection for the following relations:
$x^2+y^2-20 = 0$ and $\theta = -3\pi / 4$

So the first one is obviously a circle, and the second one, converting into rectangular form, is y/x = 1, and thus y=x. Substituting y as x in the first equation, I then get $x^2 = 10$, which yields $+- \sqrt {10}$, and thus the points of intersection should then be $(\sqrt{10},\sqrt{10})$ and $(-\sqrt{10},-\sqrt{10})$. However, the answer says that it is $(\sqrt{10},-\sqrt{10})$ and $(-\sqrt{10},\sqrt{10})$. What did I do wrong?

Also, for another problem, I need to find the intersection between these two:

> $4x^2+16y^2-64=0$ and $x^2+y^2=9$

Following a similar approach of substitution, I was able to get 4 points: $(20/3, 7/3), (-20/3, 7/3), (-20/3,-7/3), (20/3, -7/3)$. But the answer says $(3,0) and (-3,0)$...

Comment: Well, $tan 3\pi / 4$ is -1 and since it was originally $-tan 3\pi / 4$, it should be 1 and $tan \theta$ = y/x so y=x right?

Comment: Please stick to one question per post. The second one which you just edited in is unrelated to the original question, and unrelated to polar forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x = r\cos\theta, \ y= r\sin\theta$.

$\theta = - 3\pi/4$.

$r = (\sqrt{20})$.

Combining:

$x = (\sqrt{20})\cos(-3\pi/4)$ ;

$y = (\sqrt{20})\sin(-3\pi/4)$ .

$\cos(-3\pi/4) = \cos(3\pi/4) =$

$- (1/2)\sqrt{2}$.

$\sin(-3\pi/4) = - \sin(3\pi/4) =$

$ -(1/2)\sqrt{2}$.

Finally:

$x = -(\sqrt{20})/(\sqrt{2}) = -  (\sqrt{10})$;

$y = - (\sqrt{20})/(\sqrt{2})= -  (\sqrt{10})$;

For the given $\theta$ value only one point of intersection (in the third quadrant).

Comment: But then do you think my conversion of the polar relation to a rectangular one was wrong, because they way I learnt it in class it should work...?

Comment: @Helena. Not wrong, just a bit careful. Angle Theta = - 135°. Positive x axis go clockwise (downward) 135° , you end up in the third quadrant. So only one point of intersection. You replace the angleTheta by y=x , a line that cuts the circle twice(!!). The first quadrant intersection has come in via your line(draw it). You still get the third quadrant, which is the only one to be considered. Makes sense?

Comment: @Dando.Thanks for editing.

Comment: So even when I use the conversion method I should be careful that the point of intersection lies in the given quadrant (implied by the angle), right? Yes, it makes sense. Thank you :)

Comment: Helena. Yes.:):)

Answer (score 0):

How about $x=\sqrt{20}\cos \phi$, and $y=\sqrt{20}\sin \phi$. Putting $\phi = -3 \frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\phi = -3 \frac{\pi}{4}+\pi$ gives you the answer that you mentioned $(\sqrt{10}$,$\sqrt{10})$ and $(-\sqrt{10}$,$-\sqrt{10})$.

Also, for the other question $(3,0)$ cannot be the answer as it does not satisfy the first equation.